# How to call methods from multiple extensions in visual force page

Tags: controller-extension

i have created visualforce page with multiple extension.

For ex: for controller one(cntrl1) i have created method(methd1) and for controller two (cntrlr2) i have created same method(methd1). Now on button click in visualforce page i want to call methd1 from cntrlr2. How i can achieve this?

Comment: It is important what extension is defined first, bacause it overrides the same methods from all other extensions: `Overrides are defined by whichever methods are defined in the “leftmost” extension, or, the extension that is first in the comma-separated list`. Learn more about extensions: [Building a Controller Extension](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_controller_extension.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fpages_controller_extension.htm|SkinName=webhelp)

Comment: Sorry mast0r we have the same answer, didn't see your comment

Answer (score 5):

You can not really control which action you want to call. The first class in your extensions will have always the highest priority : [doc here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_extension.htm).

```
//it will always call method from cntrlr1 first
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="cntrl1,cntrlr2">

//it will always call method from cntrlr2 first
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="cntrl2,cntrlr1">
```

Better for you if you change the name of your methods.