# Multiple Extenstion with common method name

Tags: controller-extension

While using a multiple extension

```
<apex:page controller="ClassX" extensions="ClassA, ClassB">
    <apex:pageBlock>
      <apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:commandButton value="Refresh" action="{!Refresh}" />
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Two part question:

1. Now if i have Refresh function in all 3 class, which one will be called.
2. If i need to call the Refresh function from ClassB, then what is the course of action need to be taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an existing question about this: [How to call methods from multiple extensions in visual force page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18605/how-to-call-methods-from-multiple-extensions-in-visual-force-page) .

Generally, you can't really control which one to call. So it will be a better idea to change your method name. I have done this experiment about this as well. The method in the first extension will always be called.

The doc is here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm